# Accessing values from a HTTP response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a GET method to get a response. I need to access some values in this response to work in my project. How to access the value shown in below figure?

[image]

I tried

```
}).then(function (response) {

                var MLP_result

                //console.log(response);
                $scope.response = response;

                $scope.MLP_result = response.data.MLPResult;
                console.log("MLP"+ MLP_result);


            });
```

But i'm getting errors. How can I get this value into a scope

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: try console this  `console.log("MLP"+ $scope.MLP_result);`

Comment: `$scope.MLP_result = response.data; $scope.MLP_result.MLPResutlt`

Comment: To debug, try console.log('response:'+JSON.stringify(response)) and post the result here. Also, you create a variable MLP_result that you display in the console, but you do not assign value to it. I would change $scope.MLP_result = response.data.MLPResult to MLP_result = response.data.MLPResult.